# Check one checkbox should not select the whole checkbox group

Tags: angularjs, typescript, checkbox

Following is the code I am using to populate the checkbox list.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="item in vm.ItemList track by item .id">
<input type="checkbox" name ="item " ng-value="item .id" ng-model ="vm.selecteditem" />{{item.name}}
</label>
```

The above code selects all the items in ItemList. I need to select only one item from itemList. How do I do that?

Comment: What?..........

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Edit your question please

Answer (score 0):

https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

This link worked for me!

1) set checklist-model instead of ng-model 
2) set checklist-value instead of ng-value

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching the same externalized variable `vm.selectedItem` to every checkbox.  Because of this, when you check one it changes that variable to `true` in turn selecting all of the checkboxes because they are bound to the same variable which is now `true`.

My advice to you would be to attach a `selected` property to each item in `ItemList`.  Then have that attached to the ng-model as shown below.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="item in vm.ItemList track by item .id">
     <input type="checkbox" name ="item " ng-value="item .id" ng-model= "item.selected" />{{item.name}}
</label>
```